# Database exception in recycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am creating a `recycler` adapter for chat feature in my application. I am accessing stored messages from `Firebase`. However, after showing one message my app crashes giving a database exception.

```
Error:
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type 
java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.delluser.oshoguide.ChatClass
```

I am frustrated with this exception .I don't know which arraylist it is talking about as the text is obtained from model object , not an arraylist .Please help.

If I override getItemcount method , it simply crashes even without showing one output .

Also, the crash is happening because it is re-entering OnCreateViewHolder after the task is complete i.e more than one time .Later , the app crashes .

This is my code:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatClass,ViewHolder> adapter;
RelativeLayout activity_chat;
FloatingActionButton fab;
Firebase ref,mref;
TextView tv_name,tv_message;
ArrayList value;
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
RecyclerView lv_chat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    System.out.println("enter chat activity ");
    activity_chat = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.chat_activity);

    lv_chat = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lv_chat);
    lv_chat.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lv_chat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    value = new ArrayList();
    if(user!=null)
    {

        System.out.println("user is not null");
    fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        ref = new Firebase("https://oshoguide.firebaseio.com/useraccount/users");
        mref = new Firebase("https://oshoguide.firebaseio.com/Messages");

        System.out.println("running add value listener in chat activity ");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    System.out.println("value "+ds.getValue());
                    try {
                        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(ds.getValue().toString());
                        value.add(j.getString("number"));
                        value.add(j.getString("name")) ;
                        value.add(j.getString("email")) ;
                        System.out.println(value.get(0).toString()+" "+value.get(1).toString()+" "+value.get(2).toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("exception in event listener"+e.getMessage());
                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


            }
        });
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").setValue(new ChatClass(input.getText().toString(), value.get(1).toString()));
                displaychatmessage();
                input.setText("");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("exception in onclicklistener"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    Snackbar.make(activity_chat,"Welcome to Chat Station",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

else
    {
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),1);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode ==1)
    {
        if( requestCode ==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public void displaychatmessage() {

    try
    {
    System.out.println("enter dispplay mesage");

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatClass, ViewHolder>(ChatClass.class,R.layout.list_item,ViewHolder.class,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            System.out.println("entered on create view ");
              View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, ChatClass model, int position) {
          try {
              System.out.println("enter populate view ");

              viewHolder.message_text.setText(model.getText());
              viewHolder.message_user.setText(model.getUser());
              System.out.println("printed message ");
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              System.out.println("exception in populate view "+e.getMessage());
          }
        }
    };


    lv_chat.setAdapter(adapter);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("excepiton in display message "+ e.getMessage());
}
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
            TextView message_user,message_time,message_text;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        try {
            System.out.println("enter constructor of view holder ");
            message_user = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            message_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            System.out.println("exit constructor");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception on view holder ");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my firebase database:

[image]

This is my ChatClass:

```
public class ChatClass {

  String text;
  String user;
  long time;

  public ChatClass(String text, String user) {
    this.text = text;
    this.user = user;

    time = new Date().getTime();
  }

  public ChatClass() {
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  public String getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public long getTime() {
    return time;
  }

  public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try posting your logcat so people can see where the error occurs. Just giving the text of the error is not enough.

Comment: also, don't use `System.out.println("error message");`  Use `e.PrintStackTrace();`.  You are hiding your errors and making them impossible to debug

Comment: You are not using push id's which result in storing data in form (i.e all fields) of arraylist on Firebase, Use Push keys to store objects and retrieve them by event listener and cast them to same datatype in which you have pushed them to Firbase.

Comment: can you share you model class(ChatClass)?

Comment: @EnamulHaque i have shared the model class

Comment: @Pheonix I tried using push ids still it is showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just Declare `ArrayList value;` as `ArrayList<String> value;`

Then initialize it  `value = new ArrayList<>();`

Finally use it

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

            //use it hare though no change needed at all
            //use at it is 
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages")
                            .setValue(new ChatClass(input.getText().toString(), 
                             value.get(1).toString()));
            displaychatmessage();
            input.setText("");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception in onclicklistener"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: nope thats definitely not he solution , i have removed the value parameter from the ChatClass , and as far i understood now , the error was because the database was not referenced correctly . I had not used child reference to Messages object in database which is why it was referencing the entire database .

Comment: Now i'm facing a new problem , i.e it is only getting the last updated value or the last message sent , not a list of messages as the program must show